# If I move frame during Emacs startup, it moves back at the end of startup

Tags: frames, microsoft-windows, start-up

I have a fairly long startup for Emacs 24.4 on Microsoft Windows 7. I try to move the frame where I want it during startup, but it snaps back after all the startup code is done running. I don't appear to have any Emacs settings in the Registry.

The simplest way to reproduce this is to run `emacs -Q --eval '(sleep-for 3)'` and move the frame with the mouse during the sleep time. After three seconds it snaps back to its initial location.

I tried to figure out at what point in Emacs startup this movement occurs by starting up normally (no `-Q`) with the following in init file:

```
(add-hook 'after-init-hook (lambda () (message-box "after-init")))
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook (lambda () (message-box "emacs-startup")))
(add-hook 'window-setup-hook (lambda () (message-box "window-setup")))
```

If I do this, I get all three message boxes before the frame moves back.

Is there a way to keep the frame where I move it during startup?

Comment: Why not just move the frame programmatically as part of your startup inside Emacs?  You can customize the `default-frame-alist` and/or the `initial-frame-alist` -- both of which can have a frame size and location.